# Searching CRM 2011 records in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: search, bcs, dynamics-crm

I need to search Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 (onpremise or online) records in SharePoint 2010 (onpremise and preferably foundation but can go to enterprise if it is a must).

I want to know from people who have tried & succeeded in this approach.

I am thinking of BCS would be a fit in SharePoint but haven't explored much on BCS. Or can we leverage on Share point search?

Any working examples or approaches?

Thanks.